# How can I deploy my application directly from appCode IDE to my iPhone and appleWatch?

Tags: iphone, debugging, apple-watch, jetbrains-ide, appcode

I can do this in xcode easily but the debugger in xcode isn't the best. I can also deploy my app to my iPhone easily if I don't care about the appleWatch module. Is this a feature that just isn't in appCode yet?

[image: No option to change the target to my physical devices]

[image: No option to change the target to my physical devices]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't support running watchKit apps on either the device or emulator yet. Here's the ticket from jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11410